# How to write SQL join to find description of id using Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2  input tables, and I need output in string format.

[image]

I tried following query, but it does not work. How can I get the above output?

```
with 
cte1 as --table 1
(select 1 as id , 'A' as abc from dual
union
select 2 as id , 'B' as abc from dual
union
select 3 as id , 'C' as abc from dual
union
select 4 as id , 'D' as abc from dual
union
select 5 as id , 'E' as abc from dual
union
select 6 as id , 'F' as abc from dual
),
cte2 as --table2
(select 1 as id, 3 as name from dual
union
select 1 as id, 5 as name from dual
union
select 1 as id, 4 as name from dual
union
select 2 as id, 3 as name from dual
union
select 2 as id, 6 as name from dual
)
SELECT e.id, e.abc, m.id as mgr, e.abc, c.*
FROM
    cte1 e, cte2 m, cte2 c
WHERE e.id = m.id
and 
e.id=c.name;
```

Comment: Please post text rather than images. Why is the last row in your output B/B rather than B/F?

Comment: my mistake: it should be B/F .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to join each row in table 1 to two rows in table 2, and the conditions can never both be true.

You want to join each row in table 2 to two rows in table 1:

```
SELECT e.abc, m.abc
FROM cte2 c, cte1 e, cte1 m
WHERE e.id = c.id
AND m.id = c.name
ORDER BY c.id, c.name;

A A
- -
A C
A D
A E
B C
B F
```

or with 'modern' join syntax, which you should really be using:

```
SELECT e.abc, m.abc
FROM cte2 c
JOIN cte1 e ON e.id = c.id
JOIN cte1 m ON m.id = c.name
ORDER BY c.id, c.name;

A A
- -
A C
A D
A E
B C
B F
```

Comment: Old Oracle Join Syntax vs Ansi Syntax:  http://www.orafaq.com/node/2618